# Powershell local repository Get-WindowsAutoPilotInfo

Tags: powershell, csv, repository, intune

I have downloaded `Get-WindowsAutoPilotInfo` and placed on network share. I am trying to use it as a repository to run the script on mulitple pcs remote. But I can´t get it to work it says my reposity doesnt exist, but if I do `Get-PsRepository` I get the Installation Policy "Trusted" and the correct Source Location.
So I most get the `SerialNumber` which works, then `hardwarehash` (not working), and also `GroupTag` (working on this later when I've dealt with Hardware hash problem).

"Warning: Unable to find repository and therefor says Get-WindowsAutoPilotInfot is not reconginsed as name of cmdlet,function,script ...

Do you have any ideas what I do wrong?

```
Get-PSRepository

Install-Script -Repository \\Networkshare\--\---\Scripts\GetHardWareHash -Name "Get-WindowsAutoPilotInfo" -Scope AllUsers -Force

$Info = Get-WindowsAutoPilotInfo | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Hardware Hash'

$SerialNumber = Get-WmiObject win32_bios | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SerialNumber

$Model = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Model

$addInfo = @(

    $Info,

    $Model,

    $env:COMPUTERNAME

    $SerialNumber

)

 

# Concert $addInfo to a PSObject for easier exporting to CSV.

$addInfoObject = [PSCustomObject]@{

    Info         = $Info

    Model        = $Model

    ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME

    SerialNumber = $SerialNumber

}

 

$addInfo | Add-Content \\MyPath\AutoPilot $SerialNumber.log

 

# Define CSV names

$csvNameInfo = "HashFilesCollected" + ".csv"

$csvNameAddInfo = "AutoPilot " + $SerialNumber + ".csv"

 

# Export to CSV

$Info | Add-Content \\MyPath\$csvNameInfo

$addInfoObject | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";" | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Add-Content \\MyPath\$csvNameAddInfo
```

Comment: The `-Repository` parameter takes the _display name_ of an already registered repository, not a UNC path. Call `Register-PSRepository` to register the network share as a repo first, then refer to it by name when subsequently calling `Install-Script`.